# Show that binary space has a property

Tags: general-topology

A metric space X is has this property if for any points x, y ∈ X there is a bijective f : X → X with f(x) = y. Using this definition, how can one show that the binary space, consisting of all binary strings, has this property? Thanks

Comment: You need to give the definition of the metric you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: It depends on the metric. However, I suspect that you’re using one of the metrics based on the function

$$\delta(x,y)=\min\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n\ne y_n\}\;,$$

for distinct $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $y=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $X=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$. In that case, for any $x,y\in X$ let $E_{x,y}=\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n=y_n\}$, and consider the map

$$h_{x,y}:X\to X:\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\mapsto\langle\hat z_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\;,$$

where

$$\hat z_n=\begin{cases}
z_n,&\text{if }n\in E_{x,y}\\
1-z_n,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$